# How can I fix a stair to its shape?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to build an arch roof using stairs and in doing so I need stairs to get a fixed stair shape. Here are some pictures to clarify:

Two stairs together can form a corner stair:

[image: Minecraft stairs]

However when the adjoining stair is removed, the corner stair reverts to a single stair shape:

[image: Minecraft stairs]

As you can see, the stair isn't fix as a corner stair. How can I do that?

Comment: What are you asking

Comment: @stizzle84 Look at the stairs on the left on the top picture, Do you see how the left one is curved almost? Then once you destroy the stair next to it it reverts back to it's original state. I'm trying to keep it as it's curved corner state after deleting the accompanying block. The pair of stairs on the right are for reference to easier see the difference between the two pairs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, I want to note that this can only be done in Creative, but you can switch your gamemode back to survival and it will still be there.

The first step to doing this is by creating a new Creative world or switching your gamemode to Creative via cheats. The cheat to do this is `/gamemode creative` and simply type this into the Minecraft text chat. Once you're in Creative you will need to give yourself the Debug Stick by typing the cheat `/give @a minecraft:debug_stick`. Now you're ready to change the shape of a stair!

Place down your stair wherever you want it to be as if you break it or place a block next to it you will have to repeat the process. Now hold out the Debug Stick and left click (M1 on PC) until it says "selected "shape" (straight)"

[image: Using Debug Stick Image 1]

After that simply right click (M2 on PC) until your desired shape is chosen.

[image]

You can now put your stuff away and the stair will stay in that shape as long as you don't break it or place a block next to it.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: it can't be done. With certain mods however, it can possibly be *imitated*.

The way you are facing determines the direction the stair faces.

[image: image depicting direction facing and stair orientation]

If you place two stairs facing different directions (eg, one facing north, one facing east or west) they will form a corner.

[image: Minecraft Stairs]
When you destroy a block, **it will revert to it's original shape.**

[image: Minecraft Stairs]

**It also depends on what version of Minecraft you are playing, because corner stairs were released in version 1.4.2. Any version before this will not have this function**

Comment: The question is how can I stop the stair from reverting, or has that not yet been figured out?

Comment: "the stair *will* revert to it's original shape." There are currently no ways to keep it as a corner stairs without mods. (Microblocks has ways to imitate this however).

Answer (score -1):

You can lock the corner blocks into various block states (e.g. inner_left, inner_right, etc...) by tricking the logic as you position blocks. You can do things like this:

[image: wall alcove]

In general, start by adding a stair block, then another next to it with the same orientation. Finally, orient yourself 90 degrees to add the third stair which will complete a corner. Next delete the first block you positioned and the corner block should keep its state. It gets tricky to position corners near each other and takes some practice.

I first got this idea from practicing making a hot tub like this:

[Hot tub and Beach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuLoP.jpg)

I'll try to make a video on the techniques.

Comment: Neither your screenshot nor your link shows free-standing inner_left or inner_right stair blocks, which is what this question is about.

Answer (score -1):

Yes! It is possible only by copying and pasting a corner stair with world edit, though.

Comment: Could you provide more details on how this is done?